# Methods in interface not getting covered in mockito junit

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am using mockito-junit to test a piece of my code. As progressing I found out that there was an interface implemented in the main file which I was testing, when the test was running I found that the line where interface method is called get's covered but the real method doesn't get's covered.

This the code for the main file:

```
public class ExtractCurrencyDataTask {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExtractCurrencyDataTask.class);

@Autowired
private ExtractCurrencyService extractCurrencyService;

public void writeCurrencyListToFile(List<Currency> currencyList) {
    if (currencyList != null && !currencyList.isEmpty()) {
        String dir = "A path";
        String fileName = "A filename";
        String writeToFile = dir + "/" + fileName + ".writing";
        String renameFile = dir + "/" + fileName + ".dat";

        BufferedWriter writer = null;
        FileWriter fileWriter = null;
        try {
            fileWriter = new FileWriter(writeToFile);
            writer = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
            extractCurrencyService.extractCurrencyList(currencyList, writer);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error writing Currency codes", e);
        } finally {
            if (writer != null) {
                try {
                    writer.close();
                    fileWriter.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    LOGGER.info("Exception occured while closing the file writer", e);
                }
                moveFile(writeToFile, renameFile);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void moveFile(String writeToFile, String renameFile) {
    try {
        FileUtils.moveFile(FileUtils.getFile(writeToFile), FileUtils.getFile(renameFile));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.info("Exception occured while moving file from writing to dat", e);
    }
}
```

Here `extractCurrencyService` is the interface which I have mentioned.

The interface:

```
public interface ExtractCurrencyService {

    public void extractCurrencyList(List<Currency> currency, Writer writer);

}
```

This the method definition which is done another file which implements same interface Filename:ExtractCurrencyServiceImpl.java

```
public class ExtractCurrencyServiceImpl implements ExtractCurrencyService {
    private static final String SEP = "|";
    private static final String NEWLINE = "\n";

@Override
public void extractCurrencyList(List<Currency> currencyList, Writer writer) {
    if (currencyList != null) {
        currencyList.forEach(currency -> {
            String code = currency.getCode();
            String name = currency.getName() == null ? "" : currency.getName();
            Long noOfDecimals = currency.getNumberOfDecimals();
            RoundingMethodValue roundingMethod = currency.getRoundingMethod();
            boolean isDealCurrency = currency.isDealCurrency();
            String description = currency.getDescription() == null ? "" : currency.getDescription();
            try {
                writer.write(createCurrencyDataLine(code,
                                                    name,
                                                    noOfDecimals,
                                                    roundingMethod,
                                                    isDealCurrency,
                                                    description));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });
    }
}

private String createCurrencyDataLine(String code,
                                      String name,
                                      Long noOfDecimals,
                                      RoundingMethodValue roundingMethod,
                                      boolean isdealCurrency,
                                      String description) {
    return code + SEP + name + SEP + noOfDecimals.toString() + SEP + roundingMethod.toString() + SEP
            + isdealCurrency + SEP + description + NEWLINE;
}

public static <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKey(Function<? super T, Object> keyExtractor) {
    Map<Object, Boolean> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    return t -> map.putIfAbsent(keyExtractor.apply(t), Boolean.TRUE) == null;
}

}
```

This is the test file:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ExtractCurrencyDataTaskTest {

@Mock
private Currency mockCurrency;

@Mock
private ExtractCurrencyService mockExtractCurrencyService;

@Mock
private BufferedWriter mockBufferWriter;

@Mock
private Bean mockBean;

@InjectMocks
private ExtractCurrencyDataTask extractCurrencyDataTask;

@Test
public void writeCurrencyListToFileTest() {
    List<Currency> currencyList = new ArrayList();
    when(mockCurrency.getCode()).thenReturn("USD");
    when(mockCurrency.getNumberOfDecimals()).thenReturn((long) 2);
    when(mockCurrency.getRoundingMethod()).thenReturn(enum value);
    when(mockCurrency.isDealCurrency()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mockCurrency.getName()).thenReturn("US Dollars");
    when(mockCurrency.getDescription()).thenReturn("Currency Description");
    currencyList.add(mockCurrency);
    extractCurrencyDataTask.writeCurrencyListToFile(currencyList);
}
}
```

This the configuration for Autowired bean

```
@Bean
public ExtractCurrencyService extractCurrencyService() {
    return new ExtractCurrencyServiceImpl();
}
```

As you can see the real output of this process is a file will be created in a path mentioned with some data. Here in this test I am mocking the data and passing it to main file. Main file is the created file in respective path but there is no data in the file.
The data writing part is done by the interface method. This is the part where I need help.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: And note: that Currency class really looks a "data holder". You should avoid mocking such things. Just create an instance of the currency class that has the values you want to use. You strive to minimize to usage of mocks. Also note that things like Autowired and InjectMocks might conflict. You should do some research on using spring(?) CDI with Mockito.

Comment: I forgot to remove that line ,you're right it doesn't get used anywhere

Comment: What exactly doesn't get covered? Put another way: What lines would you expect to be covered that are not?

Comment: In the main file "extractCurrencyService.extractCurrencyList(currencyList, writer)" this line is getting covered.I am expecting the the data writing part which is the content inside  ExtractCurrencyServiceImpl.java to be covered

Answer (score 0):

You are injecting a mock of `ExtractCurrencyService` into your tested class. So the test is running with this mock instance instead of `ExtractCurrencyServiceImpl`. The current behaviour is that your `ExtractCurrencyDataTask`tested class is calling to `extractCurrencyService#extractCurrencyList`, but this `extractCurrencyService` is a mock, not your real implementation, so the call is done but it does nothing.

If you want to unit test `ExtractCurrencyDataTask` then thats ok, but maybe you should assert the call to `extractCurrencyService#extractCurrencyList` is done in the way you expect.

If you want to unit test `ExtractCurrencyServiceImpl` then create a unit test for this class.

If you want to test the interaction between these two classes then create an integration test where `ExtractCurrencyDataTask` has injected a real instance of `ExtractCurrencyServiceImpl`, not a mock.

Comment: Thanks for the comment ,will look into it and upvote